# Node js webhook sending HTML page in response

Tags: express, post, response, webhooks

I am using my express js app as webhook. There is a .get() method only for sending HTML page (Home Page) to browser.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //res.send('Hello World!');
    
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/views/abc.html'));

});
```

Now I have another method for handling webhook request as follow.

```
app.post('/',(req,res)=> {


const text = req.body.text;

const jsonResponse = {

    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Text response from webhook"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }

res.status(200).send(jsonResponse);
});
```

Everything works perfectly, but the above get() method sends response to the webhook which eventually ends up as an error.

I don't want to send this HTML as it is only my website home page.
How do I restrict this method from sending response to webhook.

Comment: So the webhook is made using a GET request and not a POST request?

Comment: @robertklep the First one (GET method) displays homepage in the browser. The later POST method receive a webhook request from chatbot upon each conversation step and the data will be used in the app to display for analytics purpose.
In fact I don't want to send anything in response but that HTML page is sent itself as it is inside get method.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. If the chatbot is sending a POST request, it will not receive the HTML.

Comment: Actually I was deploying to App Engine and the change in app.yaml was expected as https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#:~:text=Patterns%20are%20evaluated%20in%20the%20order%20they%20appear%20in%20the%20app.yaml%20file%2C%20from%20top%20to%20bottom.%20The%20first%20mapping%20whose%20pattern%20matches%20the%20URL%20is%20the%20one%20used%20to%20handle%20the%20request.